# PHP and Regex if word found

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm looking to only perform a strip of characters if a certain word is found in a string, so if the word numbers is matched with regex it will perform a strip all actual numbers 0-9 or preg replace them to nothing, BTW The numbers will always be wrapped in "". What would be the best way to put these two functions together? An example would be if the data was Man, Numbers are fun! "123ABC" it would return Man, Numbers are fun! "ABC" If numbers isn't present they are ignored.

Comment: Can you supply some examples?

Comment: Example. Password shouldn't have any numbers in it. "P1A2S3S4W5O6R7D" I need it to return: Password shouldn't have any numbers in it. "PASSWORD".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like some of the answers here are overcomplicated. Maybe it's just me, but this should be all you need:

```
if (stripos($str, 'numbers') !== false) {
    $str = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $str);
}
```

**EDIT:** If you only want numbers that are inside quotation marks, you might be able to do it with a regex, but I'd definitely do it this way:

```
if (stripos($str, 'numbers') !== false) {
    $arr = explode('"', $str);

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
        $arr[$i] = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $arr[$i]);
    }

    $str = implode('"', $arr);
}
```

Comment: This looks similar to @mfonda suggestion, will this version also remove the quotations and be able to find/strip the numbers among text. I need to it leave the quotation's and be able to strip all numbers from within the quotes. I'm adding another example to the pain post.

Comment: @Ryan Cooper - Nope, this should leave the quotation marks alone. It should strip out all numerals from the string and ignore everything else. Unfortunately I don't have a PHP box on hand to test it at the moment, but it should do what you've described in both examples. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php may be useful if you want more information.

Comment: This correctly removes the numbers but also removes any other numbers as well, is there a way to only match numbers within text and within quotations? So that I am 13 today, what a unlucky number. "B1D3AY" Would be left as I am 13 today, what a unlucky number. "BDAY"

Comment: @Ryan Cooper - That's possible, but it's more complicated. Your question mentioned that all numbers would be inside quotes. Do you need the more complex pattern or the one in your example?

Comment: The string changes. I do indeed only need numbers from within quotations and or among/embedded in a word/characters removed. So that the end result would be the example i used above. I've tried figuring the regex out myself but being new theres a million things to try it seems like.

Comment: I should mention i tried @mfonda 's updated version which is similar to yours with a change to the regex, i can see he escape the "'s and all but with his regex it doesnt catch the numbers in the " " and with yours it removes all numbers period.

Comment: @Ryan Cooper - Here's what I would do instead: Split the string on the `"` character using `str_split`. Then apply the regex to every odd-numbered item in the resulting array, and `implode` them back together. Much simpler, and should be faster too.

Comment: What if we used a new object defined for the quotations only? So that the main source is $data and before removing anything the script matches and defines the quotation section and everything in between as $data2 and only strips numbers from there?

Comment: @Ryan - That sounds somewhat similar to what I'm talking about, but it's probably more complicated than it needs to be. See my edit. I don't do PHP these days, so you might want to check it over, but I think it's right. You may also find http://www.regular-expressions.info/ useful.

Comment: @Ryan - Oh, and I appreciate the (removed) thought about PayPal, but it's no problem. Just an upvote and/or an accepted answer is all I need. :)

Comment: No problem, i really appreciate your help a lot. I tested that code and debug'd it a bit to try and get it to work. I have.

`if (stripos($data, 'numbers') !== false) {
    $arr = explode('"', $data);

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
        $data = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $data);
    }

    $data = implode('"', $arr);
}`

If i remove `$data = implode('"', $arr);` i can see all digits through out the string are removed, however if i leave the line in no digits are removed at all? Has to be the closest to what im trying to do, i just cant figure out what would be causing it.

Comment: On your last edit i keep getting `Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in test.php` and its not removing numbers, also there is a `Undefined index: i` on the same line.

Comment: @Ryan - That's a product of my not using PHP for a while. I typed `$arr[i]` but I meant `$arr[$i]`.

Comment: @Justin Morgan Thanks for all your help, i couldnt of done it without your help, i really appreciate it, ill vote up when i have the rep to do so.

Comment: @Justin Morgan Would it be possible with the sample you provided to define more than one keyword? So i don't have to create the same process over for a similar keyword? Such as numbers, digits or uppercase, caps, capital, etc. ?

Comment: @Ryan - If I understand what you're asking, I believe that you can pass `preg_replace` an array of regexes. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, maybe something like:

```
if (strpos($string, "numbers") !== false) {
    $string = preg_replace('/"\d+"/', '', $string);
}
```

Comment: This will strip out the quotation marks as well, and will also not work for a mix of numbers and letters as in the "ABC123" example.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: you're right, I answered this before he posted examples :)

Comment: I've tried this suggestion but it doesnt remove the numbers inside the quotations... ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the strpos function to check for the string in the first place.

Something like

`if(strpos($mystr,"Some value")!==false)
{
    /*preg_replace here.*/
}`

Comment: This will never evaluate to `true`. `strpos` returns either a number or `false`. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan Cooper: Try --

```
$input = 'Man, Numbers are fun! "123ABC"';

echo stripnums("Numbers", $input);

function stripnums($needle, $haystack)
{
    if (stripos($haystack, $needle) !== 0)
    {
        return preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $haystack);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the "numbers" flag is at position 0. I think you want `if (stripos($haystack, $needle) !== false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$str = 'Man, Numbers are fun! "123ABC"';
var_dump(preg_replace_callback("(.*\bNumbers\b.*)",
create_function(
'$matches',
'return preg_replace("/(\"[^\d]*)\d+(.*\")/", "$1$2", $matches[0]);'
),
$str));

OUTPUT:
string(27) "Man, Numbers are fun! "ABC""
```

\bNumbers\b will make sure to match word `Numbers` with word boundaries so that `xyzNumbers` and `Numbersxyz` are **NOT** matched.